# Xpath for xml inside cdata section using xslt

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt, cdata

I want to generate xpath for xml element which is inside the CDATA.

INPUT :

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
        <CSBIV xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <Response>true</Response>
            <CSBIV_CargoResult><![CDATA[
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <ShipmentRecords>
                <CustomerInfo>
                    <SoftwareVersion>6.0</SoftwareVersion>
                    <DefaultAccountNo>530901961</DefaultAccountNo>
                </CustomerInfo>
            </ShipmentRecords>  
            ]]></CSBIV_CargoResult>
        </CSBIV>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

XSLT Used to generate xpath:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:param name="path"/>
        <xsl:variable name="my-path">
            <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::*">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat('/',name())"/>
                <xsl:if test="(preceding-sibling::*|following-sibling::*)[name()=name(current())]">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat('[',count(preceding-sibling::*[name()=name(current())])+1,']')"/>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:variable>
        
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:variable name="elementXpath" select="replace($my-path, '/[a-zA-Z0-9-]*?:|/[a-zA-Z0-9-]*?','/*:')"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="xpath">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat($elementXpath,'/text()')"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            
            <xsl:for-each select="@*">
                <xsl:attribute name="{name()}" select="concat($elementXpath,'/@',name())" separator=""/>
            </xsl:for-each>
            
            <xsl:apply-templates>
                <xsl:with-param name="path" select="$my-path"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="text()"/>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So this will give me this output.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
            xpath="/*:Envelope/text()">
   <s:Body xpath="/*:Envelope/*:Body/text()">
      <CSBIV xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" xpath="/*:Envelope/*:Body/*:CSBIV/text()">
         <Response xpath="/*:Envelope/*:Body/*:CSBIV/*:Response/text()"/>
         <CSBIV_CargoResult xpath="/*:Envelope/*:Body/*:CSBIV/*:CSBIV_CargoResult/text()"/>
      </CSBIV>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

So this ignore CDATA section. So I want something like this below as output.
I want that it will give xpath for inside xml in CDATA with concating parent xpath with
**|@|CDATA|@|**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xpath="/*:Envelope/text()">
    <s:Body xpath="/*:Envelope/*:Body/text()">
        <CSBIV xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" xpath="/*:Envelope/*:Body/*:CSBIV/text()">
            <Response xpath="/*:Envelope/*:Body/*:CSBIV/*:Response/text()"/>
            <CSBIV_CargoResult xpath="/*:Envelope/*:Body/*:CSBIV/*:CSBIV_CargoResult/text()">
               <ShipmentRecords xpath="/*:Envelope/*:Body/*:CSBIV/*:CSBIV_CargoResult|@|CDATA|@|/*:ShipmentRecords/text()"> 
                    <CustomerInfo xpath="/*:Envelope/*:Body/*:CSBIV/*:CSBIV_CargoResult|@|CDATA|@|/*:ShipmentRecords/*:CustomerInfo/text()">
                        <SoftwareVersion xpath="/*:Envelope/*:Body/*:CSBIV/*:CSBIV_CargoResult|@|CDATA|@|/*:ShipmentRecords/*:CustomerInfo/*:SoftwareVersion/text()"/>
                        <DefaultAccountNo xpath="/*:Envelope/*:Body/*:CSBIV/*:CSBIV_CargoResult|@|CDATA|@|/*:ShipmentRecords/*:CustomerInfo/*:DefaultAccountNo/text()"/>
                    </CustomerInfo>
                </ShipmentRecords>
            </CSBIV_CargoResult>
        </CSBIV>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: The key thing to understand here is that the tree constructed from your XML contains a single text node containing the `CDATA` contents. `CDATA` means "character data", and the one and only function of CDATA is to tell the XML parser "don't treat the content in here as XML". So having told the XML parser not to parse it the first time around, your XSLT stylesheet has to read it as text, and turn it into a navigable tree by throwing it at another XML parser, which in recent XSLT versions can be done by calling `parse-xml()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do e.g.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">
  
  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:param name="path-prefix" as="xs:string" tunnel="yes" select="''"/>
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:attribute name="xpath" select="$path-prefix || path()"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="text()[parse-xml(.) instance of document-node()]">
    <xsl:variable name="cdata-doc" select="parse-xml(.)"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$cdata-doc/*">
      <xsl:with-param name="path-prefix" tunnel="yes" select="path(..) || '/parse-xml(.)'"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that your CDATA, due to white space before the XML declaration, doesn't parse as XML, so for that example to work you need e.g.

```
  <xsl:template match="text()[parse-xml(normalize-space(.)) instance of document-node()]">
    <xsl:variable name="cdata-doc" select="parse-xml(normalize-space(.))"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$cdata-doc/*">
      <xsl:with-param name="path-prefix" tunnel="yes" select="path(..) || '/parse-xml(normalize-space())'"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>
```

instead.

I have used the result of the `path` function to construct the xpath attribute value but you should be able to replace that with a custom function producing your wanted format.

Comment: Doing `normalize-space()` on the XML might remove rather more whitespace than you intended; it might be safer to trim leading whitespace only using a `replace()` call.

Comment: @MichaelKay, yes, I agree, I think for the element data only sample presented it doesn't matter, in general it might be better to focus on correcting the possible input in the CDATA, but as now rules or sample variants were given I went with the normalize-space as the first option that came to mind and kind of worked out for the sample.

Comment: Thanks @MartinHonnen for cdata things, but my custom xpath doesn't work for cdata , it only give embeded xml path not with the parent node xpath. ```<SoftwareVersion xpath="/*:ShipmentRecords/*:CustomerInfo/*:SoftwareVersion/text()"/>```

Comment: @neo, I don't quite understand your comment. Are you able to use the code shown in your answer? If not, because it doesn't quite create the format you want? What is the shown output format in your question with `|@|CDATA|@|` supposed to do? I don't think this is valid XPath syntax.

Comment: @MartinHonnen : I know this ` |@|CDATA|@|` in xpath is not forming a valid xpath, however I have some specific case and I have handle this , where i need to evaluate this. So what I want is to append xpath of parent node with current node of CDATA element. with ** |@|CDATA|@|**. So in this case I want something like this `<SoftwareVersion xpath="/*:Envelope/*:Body/*:CSBIV/*:CSBIV_CargoResult|@|CDATA|@|/*:ShipmentRecords/*:CustomerInfo/*:SoftwareVersion/text()"/>`

Comment: @Neo, if you want to generate an XPath of nodes then you need to use `parse-xml` to parse the CDATA section content (which is XML markup) into nodes, as shown in my answer. Don't use the built-in `path` function but just run your code to construct that strange path syntax you want.